# Using Angular and Kendo UI grid - make dataItem property bind to dropdownlist selected object

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have an array containing objects with the following data structure:

```
{
id: 1,
name: "Jane Doe",
account: {name:"somename", id:1}
}
```

The account property actually points to an object in another array.

```
[{name:"someName",id:1},{name:"anotherName",id:2}...]
```

I am using Kendo UI grid to display the data. When editing a row I want to have a dropdown show up with the **account list** so the user can select an account. I can set the value of the `account` property to be the ID or the name of the selected object and it's all good. What I need though, is to set it to point to the actual object in the array instead. I can't figure out the syntax and how to use `dataItem` to make it happen. I can't find a proper example that actually works either.

I set up this plunkr in case my description wasn't clear - http://plnkr.co/edit/TD2Sv7yN7rfgokhGpSLD?p=preview

I would like to avoid any jquery "hacks" and `onchange` handlers. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: account: $scope.accounts[0].name will show proper text instead of [object Object]

Comment: not what I was referring to. I want the dropdownlist to change the value of the bound dataItem.account property to an object and not to a primitive value.